# How to run tox on existing source code repo on Mac?

Tags: python, virtualenv, pyenv, tox, flake8

I forked the following open-source Python project, which is published to `pypi`.

https://gitlab.com/potato-oss/google-cloud/gcloud-storage-emulator

I need to make some changes to the source code. It has a tox.ini file configured for both `py36` and `py37`. I assume I make the source code changes I need, and then run `tox` to test it. Is that correct?

How do I set up my development environment for that? I tried just installing with `pip install tox`, and then ran `tox` in the source code directory. The python 3.7 tests seem to work fine, but python 3.6 and flake8 fail with these errors:

```
ERROR:  py36: InterpreterNotFound: python3.6
  py37: commands succeeded
ERROR:   flake8: InvocationError for command /Users/jacob/workspace/gcloud-storage-emulator/.tox/flake8/bin/python -m pip install --exists-action w .tox/.tmp/package/1/gcloud-storage-emulator-0.0.0.dev0.zip (exited with code 1)
```

That seems to makes sense, because I only have python 3.7 installed via brew. I tried installing and playing around with `pyenv`, but didn't get anywhere with it.

What do I need to do in order to run `tox`, and have it test with both python versions? Also, is running `tox` the right approach for development? Should I also create a virtual environment?

Comment: This is what tox does, even python36 is not installed, it will create that virtual environment and execute command on that

Comment: So why I am getting the InterpreterNotFound error?

Answer (score 2):

Run

```
tox -e py37,flake8
```

to execute a limited list of environments (exclude py36).

Or run `tox -s`; [`--skip-missing-interpreters`](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html#cmdoption-tox-s) means don’t fail tests for missing interpreters.

Comment: Thanks. That skips the py36 error, but I'm still getting a flake8 InvocationError. And if I were to want to test py36 too, how would I do that?

Comment: Install Python 3.6 and flake8. Or run `tox -e py37` only.

Comment: Thanks that is helpful. It does allow me to move ahead, and at least test on python 3.7. But it's the python 3.6 issue is still not resolved. I'm not sure how to test both versions in one invocation.

Comment: You need Python 3.6 to run `tox -e py36`.